# Why use a "do {} if" block in Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax

While browsing CPAN, I came across a block of code in [this module](http://search.cpan.org/~strytoast/Acme-SOAP-Dodger-0.002/lib/Acme/SOAP/Dodger.pm) that stumped me.

```
sub import {
  for my $mod (keys %INC) {
    do {
      delete $INC{$mod};
      $mod =~ s/\.pm$//; $mod =~ s/\//::/g;
      delete_package($mod);
    } if $mod =~ m/^SOAP/;
  }
}
```

Why would the author use a `do {} if` block instead of a regular `if` block?

Comment: Acme namespace. Why are you expecting sanity? :)

Comment: I'd personally use `for my $mod (keys %INC) { next if $mod !~ /^SOAP/; ... }`. Specifies the criteria for the loop up front, and avoids a level of indent as a bonus.

Comment: @Hugmeir haha - that's a perfectly valid answer, you should submit it :)

Answer (score 6):

Because they feel like it.  There's no real difference.  Perl has like a dozen ways to do everything.  It's just the way the language is.

Answer (score 6):

One difference is that `do { ... }` returns a value whereas an if statement doesn't (although see the comments below.)

E.g.:

```
my $x = 3;
my $z = do { warn "in the do block"; 10 } if $x == 3;
```

You can accomplish almost the same thing with the ternary operator, although you can't sequence statements inside the branches of the ternary operator.

Comment: if statements do too return values.  You just can't assign them directly due to the syntax being a little tricky.  But if you embed it properly, you can see that the if is returning a value.  Here's an equivalent piece of code:
`my $z = do { if ($x==3) { warn "in the do block";10 } }`
Your code is more succinct, though, so I still think it's a reasonable answer, just not entirely technically correct.

Comment: I agree - that's a more correct way of looking at the situation.

Answer (score 3):

To me, it seems like a way to emphasize the code *inside* the `if` more than the `if` condition itself.

Answer (score 3):

The author wanted to use the if at the end, but it has to be at the end of one statement not many.  A `do {}` is one statement, so that will work.

Personally, I would use an if statement, but it is a matter of taste whether the emphasis should be on the action or the condition.  In this case the author chose to emphasize the action.

Comment: (+1) I find it very confusing to write "Do something if something-else", just like saying "_I stay home **every day** (unless it's a work-day)_"

Answer (score 2):

Because in perl ***"There's more than one way to do it"***